# How to create one generic RewriteRule for these cases?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a lot of rules with the same structure as below.
Is there any way to have only one that will satisfy all of these cases?

```
RewriteRule ^ecology/?$ /content.php?slug=ecology [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^vraveia/?$ /content.php?slug=vraveia [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^bonus/?$ /content.php?slug=bonus [NC,L]
```

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /content.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

without luck

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /content.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

This way, you avoid rewriting an existing file or directory

With -f you test for files, and with -d for directories. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a trailing slash being included in the final URL is your problem, try making the capturing non-greedy:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /content.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

If you want to match just a single level (e.g. `ecology/` but not `ecology/one/two/`), use:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+?)/?$ /content.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```